# use 'perl module" not working as not able to add path to module in Epic

Tags: perl

I have Active state Perl 5.20.2 (32 bit) installed in my Win 7 machine. I am using Eclipse Release (4.5.1) and Epic add-on for Perl.
*I am using PERl,Eclipse and Epic for the first time.*

I have following structure for workspace and projects:

> C:\SVN\BuildToolWorkspace        -> workspace path
>   C:\SVN\BuildToolWorkspace\BuildToolPerlProj   ->project path
>   C:\SVN\BuildToolWorkspace\BuildToolPerlProj\adsp2mk.pl  -> Perl file
>   C:\SVN\BuildToolWorkspace\BuildToolPerlProj\adsp2common.pm                                -> Perl module

I see red cross in front of main Perl file adsp2mk.pl and the project.
hovering over the code show following:
[image]

I add the path to Perl include folder/file as
[image]

As I close project peoperties and open them again, the path is gone and I still have the error for the project and inside the file.

**Note/Update**:after reading the comments I did following:

[image]

However, even after refresh, I was still getting error at line 35.
Closed and opened Eclipse *and it is gone.*
However, in the navigator window, I still have Red cross in front of the project and the script as

[image]

Q1) Is this probably due to some other error picked up by syntax check?
    I don't see any red wavy line inside the script code to suggest that.
Q2) Why didn't refresh remove the error in line 35 , and I had to exit and reopen eclipse?

Comment: The include path you're trying to add looks suspicious. Can you remove `${project_loc}/` and see if the path gets added after clicking on 'Add to List'? To see if the correct include path is being used, you can create a simple Perl script which just does `print "@INC"` and check if the output has the correct paths listed.

Comment: Note: `$FindBin::RealBin` is far better than `$FindBin::Bin` as it handles shortcuts to your script too.

Comment: does `${project_loc}/"C:\SVN\BuildToolWorkspace\BuildToolPerfProj"` look anything like a valid path to you? It doesn't to me. It combines two pathname conventions and has a drive letter in the middle.

Comment: And quotes. Paths don't have quotes.

Comment: added quotes as I read in some posts that if full path has space, better to add quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the screenshot, you didn't add any paths to the list. Your list is blank.

According to the screenshot, you were about to add a string that's garbage.

The path you want is `${project_loc}/BuildToolPerlProj`<sup>[1]</sup>, and don't forget to actually click "Add to List" this time.

---

1. `C:\SVN\BuildToolWorkspace\BuildToolPerlProj` (no quotes) should also work, but since the path is within the project, it's far better to give a path relative to the project as shown above.

Comment: Q1) It probably only does a syntax check at startup and when you change the file. Q2) Don't know. Does it say what the error is? If it's till for the same error, trying changing the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the directory into @INC? I think you have to do that in a BEGIN block.

Comment: That's what `use lib` does, which is fine for when they run the script, but programmatic changes to `@INC` aren't picked up by EPIC's syntax checker, which is why it needs to be added to the project. The OP was on the right track, but fell short.